# Laravel 4 - using id's from php array_push

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, array-push

I am trying to get my query to take the values from my array_push, but can't get it working, unless of course the array is hard coded.

The array comes from a previous query

I'm new to using array_push so would value any input into how best I do this.

```
$pages = json_encode($pages);
$pages = json_decode($pages, true);

$get_ids = array();
array_push($get_ids, $pages[0]["id"]);

$get_ids = array(10);  // hardcoded 

$getpages = DB::table('pages')
        ->whereIn('id', $get_ids)
        ->select('id', 'title')
        ->get();
```

array from var_dump gives me

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "10" }
```

JSON from very first query

```
[{"id":"10","title":"About us"}]
```

Comment: Why are you JSON encoding and then decoding $pages?  Also var dump $get_ids and post what the values are.

Comment: Or maybe dd() the $pages variable to see what's going on?

Comment: As I say, I'm looking for some guidance.  When I do var_dump, it does give me the id's I'm looking for.  The encode and decode was part of my trying to get the id's from the json in my previous query.

Comment: Show us the var_dump on $pages and again on the array_push and we may be able to give you some guidance. Otherwise, we have no way of knowing what the composure of the $pages variable is. Is it an object or array? What does it contain?

Comment: Have updated my question with output.  As I am doing this I see that these are executed within a loop and the array really is only ever pulling one id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push` is a built in PHP function to add an element to the end of an array.  I think you're looking for `array_pluck`, which is a Laravel helper function to pluck a specific key from all the items in an array of arrays or array of objects.

For example:

```
$pages = array(
    array('id' => 10, 'name' => 'First'),
    array('id' => 20, 'name' => 'Second')
);

// get an array of all the page ids
$ids = array_pluck($pages, 'id'); //= array(10, 20)
```

`array_pluck` works with an array of arrays, an array of objects, or even a Laravel Collection (like the results of a database query).

In the end, your code can probably boil down to something like:

```
$get_ids = array_pluck($pages, 'id');
$getpages = DB::table('pages')
    ->whereIn('id', $get_ids)
    ->select('id', 'title')
    ->get();
```

Comment: array_pluck! Thank you so much for this.  I've been making it more complicated that it needed to be.